# How to enter a static methods for Qt Linguist QTranslator

Tags: qt, qt5, qtranslate, qt5.5, qt-linguist

I have a Qt Linguist *.ts file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.1" language="de_DE" sourcelanguage="en_GB">
<context>
    <name></name>
    <message>
        <location filename="classWithStaticMethod.cpp" line="60"/>
        <source>File</source>
        <translation>Datei</translation>
    </message>
</context>
</TS>
```

How do I enter a translation object with a static method.

`ClassWithStaticMethod.cpp has a static method where a QT_TR_NOOP("File")`

occurs at line 60 for instance. Leaving the name tags empty does nott work.

Comment: Please Insert you code specifically the part that throw that error.

Comment: @MasihAkbari There is no error. I created a translation file for a class which contains '''static''' methods only. My application does not translate within that class.