# Translate Qt-Dialogs: ColorDialog or FileDialog

Tags: qt, qt5, qdialog, qt-linguist

I have a Qt application. There I use QColorDialog to pick a QColor and QFileDialog to read/save files. My specific terms I have translated into a individual myApp_DE.qm file (works fine except for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33482054/how-to-enter-a-static-methods-for-qt-linguist-qtranslator)).

But the Qt specific dialogs, i.e. QColorDialog or QFileDialog

```
QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor(Qt::white, this, ui->label->text(),  QColorDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);
```

or

```
QString exportFileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Export dialog"), QDir::homePath(), tr("To text file (*.txt)"));
```

is still in the initial language, whereas my myApp_DE.qm was translated properly.

**How can I translate these Qt specific dialogs?**

I have UbuntuStudio in german QLocale::system() returns "de_DE", but even in the system, some buttons say "Quit" (I guess no translation availble there?).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QFileDialog dynamic translation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749267/qfiledialog-dynamic-translation)

Comment: Are you loading Qt's own translation files as well as yours?

Comment: Hm on my Linux I do not see the german translation. But on a Windows machine, I see german dialog boxes for the ready to use file openener/saver.

Comment: @peppe Yes.. all delivered *.qm files.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Sorry, I mean I added all by Qt delivered german *.qm files assistant_de.qm, designer_de.qm, linguist_de.qm, myApp_de_DE.qm, qtbase_de.qm, qtconnectivity_de.qm, qt_de.qm, qtdeclarative_de.qm, qt_help_de.qm, qtlocation_de.qm, qtmultimedia_de.qm, qtquick1_de.qm, qtquickcontrols_de.qm, qtscript_de.qm, qtxmlpatterns_de.qm.